# Rails: DropDown Selection to Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, interaction

Good Day, i have this form view/startseites/index.html.erb and i specified a methode in my people_controller, she doesnt go. I prepared some ghost code for understanding. I want to  give the entries from dropdowns with the button_to tag to the controller action checkValid. There i want to validate the entries against the database. I have to read and write from and to the table. I hope its clearly enough.

```
 class PeopleController < ApplicationController


   def checkValid
      @trainerName = params[:trainer_name]
      @sportlerName = params[:sportler_name]
      @trainerPID = params[:trainer_pid]
      @sportlerPID = params[:sportler_pid]

      #checks if sportlerID is null
       @person = Person.find(params[:sportler_pid])
        id = Person.sportler_id
        if id = nil then
             Person.sportler_id = params[:trainerPID]
         else
           puts "Sportler can have only one Trainer!"
        end

   end
   ...
```

view/startseites/index.html.erb: this code doesnt go

this should send the drop down selection to the controller action checkValid(). how can i use parameters?

```
 <%=button_to( "Zuordnung erstellen", :action => "checkValid", :controller =>"people" %>**
```

---

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td colspan="3">
       Jeder Sportler kann ein Trainer haben. </br>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Trainer</td>
       <td>
          <%= collection_select(:trainer, :trainer_id, Trainer.all, :id, :name) %>

       </td>

       <td>
         <%= link_to 'Neuer Trainer', new_person_path(:type => "Trainer") %>
       </td>

     <tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Sportler</td>
       <td>
           <%= collection_select(:sportler, :sportler_id, Sportler.all, :id, :name) %> 

       </td>
       <td>
         <%= link_to 'Neuer Sportler', new_person_path(:type => "Sportler") %>
       </td>
     <tr>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td>
        **<%=button_to( "Zuordnung erstellen", :action => "checkValid", :controller => "people") %>**
          </td>
        <tr>


    </table>
```

i added this line to my routes

```
  match '/people/checkValid', :controller => 'people', :action => 'checkValid'
```

but: No route matches {:controller=>"people/checkValid", :method=>:checkValid}

no i think it goes but

Template is missing

```
 Missing template people/checkValid, application/checkValid with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/Users/jord/testmood/app/views"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Missing template` error refers to a missing view. You should have `check_valid.html.erb` view file in `app/views/people/` directory.

Also, run `rake routes` on the command line anywhere within your app's directory. You will receive a list routes that are generated by your routes.rb file. You can double-check there if `people#checkValid` exists.

Btw, you might want to change `checkValid` to `check_valid` so you follow the naming convention for actions in Rails.

Comment: ok thanks. now it goes, but i think i need the button_tag and not button_to, because i want to validate some values. There for i dont need a alone form. I did this       <%= button_tag "Zuordnung", :controller => :people, 
                           :action => 'check_valid',
                           :trainer_id => 2,
                           :sportler_id => 2,
                           :sportler_name => "TEST",
                           :trainer_name => "TEST",
                           :method => :post %> and my controller action

Comment: def check_valid

    flash.now[:notice] = 'Message sent!'
    
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @people }
    end
  end but no response

Comment: That's correct. You need the `button_tag`. There's no `button_to` in Rails. You might want to refer to [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org) when you are unsure.

I'm guessing what you want to do is to check if the params are being passed? To do that, you could check the development log or have `<%= params debug %>` in the view where your controller will redirect to.

You could add `redirect_to root_path` to your `people#check_valid` action. Add the `params debug` line I mentioned earlier to the view where root is routed.