# how to perform controller's action by selecting dropdown's option in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, haml

I am very fresher in ROR and in my app I have `role` model. Now on it's index page I have put dropdown list on the top so user can select the particular role and perform action accordingly by just selecting dopdown list option and when click to submit that action should be performed. I don't want to do that by `link_to` can anyone please explain me which steps I need to perform. i know it can be performed by Jquery but I am also poor in that.

for your easy understand I have uploaded a screen shot
[image]

I have seen this [Rubyforum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4404168) , [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798715/rails-dropdown-selection-to-controller-action) but still can't understand. I appreciate if anyone can explain me in details step by step..or provide me better and easy resource. I can't understand from where to start?

Some code:

**index.html.haml**

```
.user_details.clearfix
  = form_for :role do |f|
    %h3 Listing Roles
    .selectbox.blueselect.frd
      = f.select(:name, [['Delete', 'delete'], ['Change Status', 'changestatus']],{:include_blank=> 'Select Action'},{:class=>'select1'})
      = f.submit 'Submit', :class=>'blue_btn frd'

    %label.actionlabel Actions
#accordion.tablerow.clearfix
  %table.tablelist{border: "0", cellpadding: "0", cellspacing: "0", width: "100%"}
    %tr
      %th{align: "left", valign: "middle"}  
      %th{align: "left", valign: "middle"} Sr. No.
      %th{align: "left", valign: "middle"} Name
      %th{align: "left", valign: "middle"} Description
      %th{align: "left", valign: "middle"} Is Active?
      %th{align: "left", valign: "middle"} Access Module
      %th{align: "left", valign: "middle"}
      %th{align: "left", valign: "middle"}
    - @count=0
    - @roles.each do |role|
      %tr
        %td{align: "left", valign: "middle"}
          %input.checkbox{type: "checkbox", :id=>'chkbox', :value=> role.id, :onclick=>"validate(this.value)"}
        %td{align: "left", valign: "middle"}= @count += 1
        %td{align: "left", valign: "middle"}= role.name
        %td{align: "left", valign: "middle"}= role.description
        %td{align: "left", valign: "middle"}= role.isactive
        %td{align: "left", valign: "middle"}= role.access_module_roles.map { |amr| amr.access_module.name }.join(", ")
        %td{align: "left", valign: "middle"}= link_to 'Show', role
        %td{align: "left", valign: "middle"}= link_to 'Edit', edit_role_path(role)
        %td{align: "left", valign: "middle"}= link_to 'Delete', role_path(role), :method=> :delete
  %br
  = link_to 'New Role', new_role_path, :class=>'blue_btn'
```

Anyone need more detail then I can update.. want to perform `delete` action

Answer (score 1):

Without using javascript, you can't change the action from a select.  The action is determined by the url which is called by the form submission, which in turn is specified in the `action` attribute of the form.  All that a select, or any other form input can do, is to change the **params** that are submitted to that url.

This doesn't mean that all is lost, however:  it means that you either need to

a) change the form's `action` attribute with javascript when the select changes

b) change your controller code so that the form submits to a single fixed url, but the action in the controller does different things depending on the params.  Something like

```
#in the controller
@foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
if params[:foo_action] == "destroy"
  @foo.destroy
elsif params[:foo_action] == "update"
  @foo.update_attributes(:params[:foo])
...etc
```

Comment: For option b? Well obviously you'll need an entry in your routes file which connects the URL (or the path part of it to be specific) in question to the controller and action in question. You might have one already, I don't know.

Comment: I am trying to get this solution without javascript.. When I will be done.. Will post the answer here.. For your response I would like to give 1+ :)

Comment: Just FYI, it's a common pattern to keep the number of routes in your app very small and do as much with params as possible.  With APIs for example, often there is a single path that all API requests come through.  Obviously this goes against REST but it gives you a lot more flexibility with how to handle things.

Comment: you are right gentleman... I am aware about it and by using params I have solved this issue without using javascript.. :) Thanks for your time and responses... heartily appreciate